Trouble Displaying PDF with Expo Go
I'm working on a React Native application where I need to display PDF files. I've attempted two different approaches, one using react-native-webview and the other with react-native-pdf, but I'm running into issues with both.
This is how the project was created :
-npx create-expo-app my-app --template
- Blank (TypeScript)
Firstly, with react-native-webview, the PDF is downloaded instead of displayed in the app:
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

interface PDFViewerProps {
    uri: string;
}

const PDFViewer: React.FC<PDFViewerProps> = ({ uri }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <WebView
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                source={{
                    uri: `${uri}?inline=true`,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Disposition': 'inline' 
                    }
                }}
                style={styles.webview}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

However, rather than displaying the PDF inline, it triggers a download in the app. The server is configured to handle inline content disposition.
Secondly, when I switch to using react-native-pdf, I encounter a runtime error stating:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fs' of undefined

Here's the code snippet for that:
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import Pdf from "react-native-pdf";

interface URLType {
  uri: string;
}

const PDFViewer: React.FC<URLType> = ({ uri }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pdf
        source={{ uri }}
        style={styles.pdf}
        onError={(error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

The expected outcome is to display the PDF content within the app without downloading it, and I'd like to use the most straightforward and reliable method possible. Any insights into why these errors are occurring, or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Whenever we need to add incompatible packages with expo go then follow the below procedures for development mode

Make sure to have eas account and link with project by eas build:configure

npx expo install expo-dev-client

eas build --profile development --platform android /
eas build --profile development-simulator --platform ios

Install the generated build in your device

in project terminal run command npx expo start --dev-client

Enter the generated url in the enter url TextInput of your app.


THIS CAN BE USED FOR TESTING/DEVELOPMENT SUCH AS IN APP PDF READER.
And that's it!!!!
And for opening pdf in app, you can use
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import Pdf from "react-native-pdf";

  const PdfResource = { uri: pdfUrl, cache: true };

  return (
      <Pdf
        trustAllCerts={false}
        source={PdfResource}
        style={styles.pdf}
        onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath) => {
          console.log(`number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
        }}
      />
  );
};

export default PdfRead;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pdf: {
    flex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
  },
});

This component can be used for showing pdf in app after you setup your dev client as expo go doesn't support react-native-pdf lib directly. So, this is the work around.
